# Faster xml object mapper converting java object to json incorrectly?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

Hi I am having an json data file containing an array of objects. I am reading the json file and convert it into a list of java object . However when i use the object mapper to convert it to json document i am seeing values printed with a precision followed by zeros . any idea how can i fix it .

so following is my json data file.

```
[
  {
    "inventory": "SMS",
    "msg_text": "This is random text",
    "status": "ENROUTE",
    "@timestamp": "2019-09-02T03:26:26.770Z",
    "o_error": "",
    "flight_id": "92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed",
    "recipient": 420736408283,
    "account_id": "a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f",
    "sender": 8800111,
    "submission_ts": 1567681407,
    "campaign_id": "6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0",
    "nof_segments": 1,
    "@version": 1,
    "delivery_ts": 1558761537
  },
  {
    "inventory": "SMS",
    "msg_text": "This is random text",
    "status": "ENROUTE",
    "@timestamp": "2019-09-02T09:48:09.213Z",
    "o_error": "",
    "flight_id": "92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed",
    "recipient": 420736408283,
    "account_id": "a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f",
    "sender": 8800111,
    "submission_ts": 1567681407,
    "campaign_id": "6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0",
    "nof_segments": 1,
    "@version": 1,
    "delivery_ts": 1549246209
  }]
```

The following is the code to read the file , convert it into a json object and print .

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

objMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

```
List<MessageHistory> messageHistories = objMapper.readValue(getMessageHistoryResourceAsStream(),
                    objMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MessageHistory.class));
for (int i = 0; i < messageHistories.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(objMapper.writeValueAsString(messageHistories.get(i)));

}
```

output is below

```
{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-04T17:43:03.518Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408281","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407.000000000,"delivery_ts":1562941055.000000000}
{"inventory":"SMS","msg_text":"This is random text","status":"ENROUTE","@timestamp":"2019-09-01T09:05:45.540Z","o_error":"","flight_id":"92348fa1-ca6c-456a-b3b2-85fba2d2deed","recipient":"420736408283","account_id":"a56f7e14-20f9-40e6-90c6-10604140ac5f","sender":"8800111","campaign_id":"6f2abca3-b46d-43f3-91be-3278a8dd7dc0","nof_segments":1,"@version":1,"submission_ts":1567681407.000000000,"delivery_ts":1558368683.000000000}
```

you can see submission_ts and delivery_ts has .000000000 to it ..

so following is my MessageHistory.java file what i use to bind the json data to object.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MessageHistory {

    @JsonProperty("inventory")
    private String inventory;

    @JsonProperty("msg_text")
    private String messageText;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("@timestamp")
    private Instant timeStamp;

    @JsonProperty("o_error")
    private String error;

    @JsonProperty("flight_id")
    private UUID flightId;

    @JsonProperty("recipient")
    private String recipient;

    @JsonProperty("account_id")
    private UUID accountId;

    @JsonProperty("sender")
    private String sender;

    @JsonProperty("campaign_id")
    private UUID campaignId;

    @JsonProperty("nof_segments")
    private Integer segmentCount;

    @JsonProperty("@version")
    private Integer version;

    @JsonProperty("submission_ts")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, timezone = "UTC")
    private Instant submissionTimeStamp;

    @JsonProperty("delivery_ts")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, timezone = "UTC")
    private Instant deliveryTimeStamp;

    public String getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(String inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Instant getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Instant timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public UUID getFlightId() {
        return flightId;
    }

    public void setFlightId(UUID flightId) {
        this.flightId = flightId;
    }

    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public UUID getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(UUID accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public UUID getCampaignId() {
        return campaignId;
    }

    public void setCampaignId(UUID campaignId) {
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
    }

    public Integer getSegmentCount() {
        return segmentCount;
    }

    public void setSegmentCount(Integer segmentCount) {
        this.segmentCount = segmentCount;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Instant getSubmissionTimeStamp() {
        return submissionTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setSubmissionTimeStamp(Instant submissionTimeStamp) {
        this.submissionTimeStamp = submissionTimeStamp;
    }

    public Instant getDeliveryTimeStamp() {
        return deliveryTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTimeStamp(Instant deliveryTimeStamp) {
        this.deliveryTimeStamp = deliveryTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

I am annotating the fileds

```
@JsonProperty("submission_ts")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, timezone = "UTC")
private Instant submissionTimeStamp;

@JsonProperty("delivery_ts")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT, timezone = "UTC")
private Instant deliveryTimeStamp;
```

really appreciate any help to solve why the objects when printed as json has that .000000 attached to those two fields
thank you

Comment: You can try google's gson for json to java object conversion..Gson gson = new Gson(); gson.fromJson(json object, Java class name.class)

Comment: @NKR What's the advantage of using Gson instead of Jackson in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disable the [`WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS) feature.

From the documentation:

> Feature that controls whether numeric timestamp values are to be written using nanosecond timestamps (enabled) or not (disabled);

---

You can either disable it in `ObjectMapper` (which applies to all fields):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
```

Or disable it at field level:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER,
            without = Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
private Instant instant;
```

---

If you intend to use this configuration in multiple fields, you may want to consider [`@JacksonAnnotationsInside`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.html) which allows you to create a custom annotation which contains one or more Jackson annotations:

```java
@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER,
            without = Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
public @interface JsonTimestamp {

}
```

Then simply use the newly created annotation:

```java
@JsonTimestamp
private Instant instant;
```

Comment: did lots of search and finally this answer works, using the annotation
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER, without = Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
Many thanks!